# Holoviews RGB coordinates

Tags: python, python-xarray, holoviews

I am attempting to read a multiband tif file (4 bands - [Blue, Green, Red, Infrared]) into an [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/), then display as RGB using [HoloViews](http://holoviews.org/) within a Jupyter notebook. For reference, I'm loosely following the RGB png example here: http://holoviews.org/reference/elements/matplotlib/RGB.html

The final RGB image does display, however, I lose the x/y coordinate dimensions by combining the DataArrays using np.dstack. The x/y coordinates in the final image default to ~ -0.5 - +0.5.

I'm at a loss how to carry through the coordinate dimensions through the process, or potentially how to apply the original coordinate dimensions to the final image.

```
# read .tif
ximg = xarray.open_rasterio('path/to/tif')
print('1.', type(ximg), ximg.coords['x'].values)

# convert to hv.Dataset
r_ds = hv.Dataset(ximg[2,:,:], kdims=['x','y'], vdims='Value')
g_ds = hv.Dataset(ximg[1,:,:], kdims=['x','y'], vdims='Value')
b_ds = hv.Dataset(ximg[0,:,:], kdims=['x','y'], vdims='Value')
print('2.', type(r_ds), r_ds.dimension_values('x'))

# scale to uint8
r = np.squeeze((r_ds.data.to_array().astype(np.float64)/8190)*255).astype('uint8')
g = np.squeeze((g_ds.data.to_array().astype(np.float64)/8190)*255).astype('uint8')
b = np.squeeze((b_ds.data.to_array().astype(np.float64)/8190)*255).astype('uint8')
print('3.', type(r), r.coords['x'].values)

# combine to RGB
dstack = np.dstack([r, g, b]) # lose coordinate dimensions here
print('4.', type(dstack), 'NO COORDS')
rgb = hv.RGB(dstack, kdims=['x','y'])
print('5.', type(rgb), rgb.dimension_values('x'))

1. <class 'xarray.core.dataarray.DataArray'> [557989.5 557992.5 557995.5 ... 563194.5 563197.5 563200.5]
2. <class 'holoviews.core.data.Dataset'> [557989.5 557989.5 557989.5 ... 563200.5 563200.5 563200.5]
3. <class 'xarray.core.dataarray.DataArray'> [557989.5 557992.5 557995.5 ... 563194.5 563197.5 563200.5]
4. <class 'numpy.ndarray'> NO COORDS
5. <class 'holoviews.element.raster.RGB'> [-0.49971231 -0.49971231 -0.49971231 ...  0.49971231  0.49971231
  0.49971231]
```

Example showing desired coordinates, using HoloViews images created from `r_ds`, `g_ds`, and `b_ds` above:
[image: desired coords]

Example showing undesired coordinates, using HoloViews RGB, named `rgb` above:
[image: undesired coords]

Comment: Does the Datashader LANDSAT example help? http://datashader.org/topics/landsat.html

Comment: Yes, that does help. I had found this example, but was hesitant to pursue it for fear of going down yet another rabbithole to solve this seemingly simple problem. I've posted an answer, but if you want to explain it further, I'm happy to accept that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Landsat example mentioned in comments uses a `data` parameter of the form `(xdim, ydim, R, G, B, A)`, which applies the desired x/y coordinates to the image.

Landsat example: http://datashader.org/topics/landsat.html

```
rgb = hv.RGB(
    (
        ximg['x'],
        ximg['y'],
        r.data[::-1],
        g.data[::-1],
        b.data[::-1]
    ),
    vdims=list('RGB')
)
```

[image]