# How do I plot an irregularly gridded RGB using holoview QuadMesh?

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews, datashader

I am working with irregularly gridded earth observation data, and am trying to find ways to plot this efficiently using holoview with bokeh as the backend. **I wish to avoid interpolation if at all possible**.

Plotting regularly gridded data seems simple enough via the RGB method [Holoviews RGB coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53074337/holoviews-rgb-coordinates). However, the approach for irregularly gridded data seems to be to use Quadmesh. Implementing this, and using datashading to conserve memory, is simple enough for a single channel of data mapped to a defined colourmap, e.g.;

```
qmesh = hv.QuadMesh((lon, lat, band_dict['Oa08_radiance']))
datashade(qmesh, cmap=plt.cm.viridis).opts(width=np.shape(lon)[0], height=np.shape(lon)[1])
```

So far, so good, but despite my best efforts, I can't find a way to implement this for 3-channel RGB. In my previous matplotlib attempts to achieve the same thing, I passed either a tuple to the pcolormesh "color" argument, or a LinearSegmentedColormap to the "cmap" argument. Neither work in this case.

Surprisingly, I can find no pre-existing examples of this; which makes me wonder if what I am attempting is impossible. Has anyone else attempted the same and can help?

Comment: HoloViews does not offer an RGB QuadMesh element. I think this could be done using a Compositor given three or four datashaded QuadMesh elements, combining them into one final RGB element for display. Probably about 5 lines of code, but I haven't tried it. If you post an example with data at the HoloViz discourse we can probably help.

Comment: Thanks @JamesA.Bednar, I'll head to HoloViz and post the example there.

Comment: 2 years later, and I'm looking for those 5 lines of code ...

Answer (score 0):

Can't promise this is the best way, but I got the job done using a custom [element transform](https://holoviews.org/user_guide/Transforming_Elements.html#defining-custom-operations) subclassing `holoviews.operation.Operation`. Here is an application of my solution recreating the [RGB](https://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/RGB.html) example.

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv

hv.extension("bokeh")

x, y = np.mgrid[-50:51, -50:51] * 0.1

r = 0.5*np.sin(np.pi + 3 * x ** 2 + y ** 2) + 0.5
g = 0.5*np.sin(x ** 2 + 2 * y ** 2) + 0.5
b = 0.5*np.sin(np.pi / 2 + x ** 2 + y ** 2) + 0.5

hv.RGB(np.stack([r,g,b], axis=-1))
```

Instead of this hv.RGB, assume the `x` and `y` are actually an irregular grid. In that case, label your data and create three rasterized images.

```
from holoviews.operation.datashader import rasterize

dataset = xr.Dataset(
    data_vars={
        "R": (("x", "y"), r),
        "G": (("x", "y"), g),
        "B": (("x", "y"), b),
    },
    coords={
        "X": (("x", "y"), x),
        "Y": (("x", "y"), y),
    },
)
red, green, blue = [rasterize(hv.QuadMesh(dataset[i])) for i in ("R", "G", "B")]
```

Each color channel is now a DynamicMap that returns an Image. The built in `holoviews.operation.factory` really ought to do the next job, which is to map the simple operation of combining overlaid images into an RGB over each DynamicMap ... but I can't get it to work. Hence, a custom operation.

```
from holoviews.operation import Operation

class rgb(Operation):
    def _process(self, overlay, key=None):
        dataset = xr.merge((image.data for image in overlay.values()))
        array = dataset.to_array("band").transpose(..., "band")
        return hv.RGB(array)

rgb(red * green * blue)
```

The resulting DynamicMap appears to work like the usual `rasterize` output, but on the overlaid channels.